# Python Requests - Why is RequestsCookieJar[] object sometimes empty?

Tags: python, python-requests

I've seen a couple of answers on this subject, but I still don't quite understand. Why is the `RequestsCookieJar[]` object sometimes empty? In the example below, for instance, it returns empty.

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://brave.com/')
print(r.cookies)
```

Output:

```
<RequestsCookieJar[]>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site (`brave.com`) does not use the header `Set-Cookie`. therefore, you have no cookies in your jar

Comment: Thanks for answering! So, does it mean it has no cookies at all, or they are kept elsewhere?

Comment: @RobinSage - the site might or might not use cookies. all the cookies a site will use depends on the logic of the site itself (thus, unless you have the source code of the site you will not be able to tell). Some of these cookies might be "hidden" - meaning, only if you send a specific cookie, you will get a different response or different user experience (e.g. administration page). however if you have these cookies in your jar, the cookies are sent to the site regardless. The location to keep cookies is only within the jar (there is no other place)

Comment: P.S. in order to keep cookies between requests take a look at [Session](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/)  This `Session` will enable you to keep cookies between multiple requests